# Vim cursorshape in OS X Terminal

Tags: vim, osx-snow-leopard

I compiled vim 7.3 with +cursorshape and added the following to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set t_SI = "\<Esc>]12;purple\x7" 
set t_EI = "\<Esc>]12;blue\x7"
```

but Terminal.app still displays the same grey cursor, irrespective of the current vim mode. Terminal identifies itself as xterm-color, so I thought the information in `:help termcap-cursor-shape` would apply.

Am I missing something?